# Пытаюсь сделать сортировку расчёской, но выводит ошибки. Подскажите, как исправить, чтобы код работал корректно

Tags: python, сортировка

[image: Сам код]

[image: Ошибка, которую выводит код]

Проблема в коде с сортировкой расчёской!

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть в виде текста, чтобы каждый мог к себе скопировать и запустить.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. такие вопросы будут закрывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А, я понял. У вас получается примерно следующее:

```
x = 42
x = x / 1,247
print(x)
```

Вывод, внезапно видим кортеж:

```
(42.0, 247)
```

Запятая в питоне обозначает кортеж. Даже если скобки не написать. Фактически у вас получилось так:

```
x = ((x / 1), 247)
              ^^^ второй элемент кортежа
      ^^^^^ первый элемент кортежа
```

В общем, поменяйте запятую на точку:

```
x = x / 1.247
```